# How to use a promise in a component to show an alert in the view

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, promise, angular-promise

I have an Angular component that have a method that's being called when a form is submitted. And its calling a service method which returns a promise and im trying to use that to trigger an alert like this :

Component :

```
  user: User;
  private readonly notifier: NotifierService;

  constructor(private userService : UserService, 
    private modalService: NgbModal, notifierService: NotifierService) {
        this.notifier = notifierService;
  }

  onFormSubmit(onSubmitValue: any){
   this.user = {
       name: onSubmitValue.name,
       email: onSubmitValue.email,
       contactNumber: onSubmitValue.contactNumber,
       isOnline: false
   }

   let respose = this.userService.createUser(this.user);
      respose.then(response => { 
         this.notifier.notify('success', 'User creation success');
      }, error => 
         this.notifier.notify('fail', 'User creation failed');
    );
 }
```

Service :

```
    createUser(user: User) {
       let promise =  new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) =>{
         this.firestore
           .collection("users")
           .add(user);
       });

       return promise;
    }
```

The service is calling firestore collection to add the object.
The alert is not getting triggered when i try to use it in the component. Am i missing something here or am i handling the promise wrong? Im fairly new to this.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might need to RETURN the actual promise

```js
    createUser(user: User) {
       let promise =  new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) =>{
         // Here add return
         return this.firestore
           .collection("users")
           .add(user);
       });

       return promise;
    }
```

Or, since add returns a promise you can do this

```js
    createUser(user: User) {
       return this.firestore
           .collection("users")
           .add(user);
    }
```

About your comment:
You need to `catch` the error to allow it

```js
let respose = this.userService.createUser(this.user);

respose
 .then((response) => { 
  this.notifier.notify('success', 'User creation success');
 })
 .catch((error) => { 
  this.notifier.notify('fail', 'User creation failed');
 });
```

Comment: yes it worked. But even if i change the firebase configs, the error clause is not catching that to trigger the error alert